# What are the limitations for app development on the kindle fire?

Tags: android, mobile, kindle, kindle-fire

I think its time to ask this question since the kindle fire has been out a few days now.

I've been hovering around the net to see just how different android vs kindle fire development differed.

How different are the 2 in terms of developing apps?

Is it true that standard apps in the marketplace aren't available?

Comment: Yes see the FAQ that Kristopher linked to. They do not use the standard Android market, Amazon has its own Android Amazon App Store.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Amazon's FAQ here: https://developer.amazon.com/help/faq.html#KindleFire

Answer (score 0):

Over 75% of android apps will run fine on Kindle Fire as is. As for the apps that don't work, it's because they could be using Google APIs. These APIs have to be replaced with Amazon APIs.

In short, Amazon has tired their best to keep it as simple as possible for an android app developer to switch to Kindle app development.